# How do I keep a button disabled untill all the fields are filled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How would I constantly check if multiple fields have input, and once all fields have input enable the button? or is is as simple as

```
if( textbox1.text && textbox2.text && textbox3.text && ...){button1.isEnabled = true;}
```

is there an update method like in unity to check for changes?

Comment: simply bind to a change event for the textboxes, and trigger logic checking the condition there, there are also many more sophisticated soluutions introduced by wpf, I guess you need some  reading on the way it works

Comment: Ohh I see! Thank you. And any good references for these better solutions?

Comment: do you intend to follow command pattern ? I recommend you must, this will then be easy peasy !

Comment: Alternatively, do `listing` on your textboxes at form load **once** and then, in the run time, you check with `LINQ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link all the textboxes to the same `TextChanged` event and then evaluate them to see if all textboxes has been completed.

```
private void textBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableButton();
}


private void EnableButton()
{
    button1.Enabled = !Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use command pattern and it should then look like this --

Your command class --

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Your button code --

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
```

Your command property --

```
public ICommand EnabledCommand { get; set; }
```

In your constructor --

```
ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonCommandHandler, CanClick);
```

Your command handler --

```
private void ButtonCommandHandler(object obj)
    {
        // Do what ever you wanna
    }
```

Your can execute handler --

```
 private bool CanClick(object arg)
    {
        return textbox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && textbox2.Text.Trim().Length > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Command is the best way (I would use a library for this: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) CanClick is correct, but now you should trigger CanExecuteChanged when the textbox or textbox 2 has changed.

Comment: great illustration how simple things can get complicated... I'd say antipattern unless really sophisticated logic is involved

Comment: SO isn't about providing solutions its about guiding the right way, would you yourself do it the way OP is doing ?, if you think command pattern is complex then .... Good Luck !

Comment: then what? than Im a bad programmer? or stupid? It's simply an overkill for such simple example. Cool to prove you can program, not best if you're really implementing something to be easy to use and understand. Especially if your level is to ask questions like above on SO

Comment: read my comment on question, I am just advocating best practices, this is no way an overkill in practical world. isn't  ?